# Linearity of a function.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I am requested to determine wether these functions are linear or not; to do that, I've to verify both the necessary conditions that are:

$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$

$f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$

Now, my functions are:

$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_1+x_2,x_3)$
 f:R3→R2

$f(x_1,x_2) = (x_2,-x_1,x_1+3x_2)$
 f:R2→R3

How can I proceed??

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Hint: consider $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ in the first case, and $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$. It helps seeing the situation clearly.

Comment: Say what are the domains of these functions? I guess the first one is $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, but make it clear!

Comment: Yes, sorry.. the domain is what you said in the first one..

Comment: Also, for the second one: $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Make it clear in the question.

Comment: Sorry...I've corrected now..  but someone can help me solve it?

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, remembering that by definition for $a = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n)$ addition is defined by $a+b = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) + (b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n) = (a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2, \dots, a_n + b_n)$ and that multiplication by a scalar is defined as $\alpha a = (\alpha a_1, \alpha a_2, \dots, \alpha a_n)$ for any scalar $\alpha$.

We may shorten any proof attempt by proving the statement: for all $x, y \in \mathscr{D}(f)$ and all $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ we have $f(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)$ (since setting alpha and beta equal to 1 gives the first condition and setting beta equal to zero gives the second condition).

Consider for the first one, which was defined as $f( (x_1, x_2, x_3) ) = (x_1 + x_2, x_3)$
for the points $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $y = (y_1, y_2, y_3)$ and arbitrary scalars $\alpha, \beta$.

Then $f(\alpha x + \beta y) = f( (\alpha x_1 + \beta y_1, \alpha x_2 + \beta y_2, \alpha x_3 + \beta y_3)) = (\alpha x_1 + \beta y_1 + \alpha x_2 + \beta y_2, \alpha x_3 + \beta y_3)~~~~$

*here i just used the definition of addition of vectors and scalar multiplication and the definition of the function itself*

$ = (\alpha( x_1 + x_2) + \beta (y_1 + y_2), \alpha x_3 + \beta y_3)  ~~~$*grouped x's and y's together and factored out scalar constants*

$=\alpha (x_1 + x_2, x_3) + \beta (y_1 + y_2, y_3) = \alpha f((x_1, x_2, x_3)) + \beta f((y_1, y_2, y_3)) = \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)~~~~$ *seperated vector into addition of two vectors and factored out scalar constant, then used definition of our function to complete*

Therefore, the first function is indeed linear.  Try it now with the second function yourself and see where you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3),y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$. Then $x+y=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3)$ and

\begin{align}
f(x+y) &=f(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3)\\ 
 &=(x_1+y_1+x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3)\\
 &=(x_1+x_2,x_3)+(y_1+y_2,y_3)\\
 &=f(x)+f(y).
\end{align}
So $f$ is linear. Others can be shown similarly.

**EDIT** $f$ is additive.

Comment: That shows the first property of linearity only.  Left out scalar multiplication which is also important.

Comment: \begin{align}f(\alpha x) &=f(\alpha x_1,\alpha x_2,\alpha x_3)\\ &=(\alpha x_1+\alpha x_2,\alpha x_3)\\ &=\alpha (x_1+x_2,x_3)\\ &=\alpha f(x)\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**First one** : $f((x_1, x_2, x_3) + (y_1, y_2, y_3)) = f((x_1 + y_1, x_2 + y_2, x_3 + y_3) = (x_1 + y_1 + x_2 + y_2, x_3 + y_3) = (x_1 + x_2, x_3) + (y_1 + y_2, y_3) = f((x_1, x_2, x_3)) + f((y_1, y_2, y_3))$

$f(a(x_1, x_2, x_3)) = f((ax_1, ax_2, ax_3)) = (ax_1 + ax_2, ax_3) = (a(x_1 + x_2), ax_3) = a(x_1 + x_2, x_3) = af((x_1, x_2, x_3))$

**Second one** :
$f((x_1, x_2) + (y_1, y_2)) = f((x_1 + y_1, x_2 + y_2)) = (x_2 + y_2 - x_1 - y_1, x_1 + y_1 + 3x_2 + 3y_2) = (x_2 - x_1, x_1 + 3x_2) + (y_2 - y_1, y_1 + 3y_2) = f((x_1, x_2)) + f((y_1, y_2))$

$f(a(x_1, x_2)) = f((ax_1, ax_2)) = (ax_2 - ax_1, ax_1 + 3ax_2) = a(x_2 - x_1, x_1 + 3x_2) = af((x_1, x_2))$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick; *if* your functions are linear, then they are obtained by
$$
f(x)=Ax
$$
for some matrix $A$, where vectors are written as columns.

The matrix can also be written explicitly: its columns are exactly $f(e_1)$, $f(e_2)$ and $f(e_3)$ (in the first case where the domain is $\mathbb{R}^3$) where $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$ are the vectors in the standard (or canonical) basis.

Since, by definition,
$$
f(e_1)=f\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
f(e_2)=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
f(e_3)=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix},
$$
the matrix is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, for a generic vector,
$$
Ax=A\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1+x_2\\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}=f(x)
$$
and this ends the verification.

Try your hand with the second map.